# how can refresh Activity when I finish Activity then close Activity?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

how can refresh Activity when I finish Activity then close Activity?

I have two Activity,

The first one is GroupInfoActivity, when users submit information in GroupPostActivity, it's will finish GroupPostActivity then back to GroupInfoActivity.

in the GroupInfoActivity I have set onActivityResult

```
final int RESULT_CODE=101;

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode ==RESULT_CODE) {
            setResult(1,(new Intent()));
        }
    }
```

And the GroupPostActivity I have set

```
final int RESULT_CODE=101;
Intent intent=new Intent(GroupPostActivity.this,GroupInfoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("gid",getIntent().getStringExtra("gid"));
intent.putExtra("groupname",getIntent().getStringExtra("gname"));
setResult(RESULT_CODE, intent);
finish();
```

But when I finish GroupPostActivity, the GroupInfoActivity cannot refresh and get new data.

where has problem?

I dont want to use startActivity(intent) this method, because it's more avtivity.

Comment: use the `onResume` method in GroupInfoActivity

Comment: same, still no reload

Comment: can you explain your path of GroupPostActivity?

Comment: mainActivity (GroupFragment) ->  GroupInfoActivity  -> GroupPostActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GroupInfoActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode ==RESULT_CODE) {

            if (data != null) {

                String gid = data.getStringExtra("gid");
                String groupname = data.getStringExtra("groupname");

                //refresh or do anything you want
            }
        }
    }
```